# Proving that if $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\exists x_n \in \mathbb R: |x_n - a| < \frac{1}{n}$, then $a \in \bar S$

Tags: general-topology

This exercise is in my general topology textbook:

> Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ and $a \in \mathbb R$. Prove that $a \in \bar S$ if and only if $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\exists x_n \in S: |x_n - a| < \frac{1}{n}$.

So I proved that if $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\exists x_n \in S: |x_n - a| < \frac{1}{n}$, then $a \in \bar S$. But I'm having trouble proving that if $a \in \bar S$, then $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\exists x_n \in S: |x_n - a| < \frac{1}{n}$.

---

**My approach:**

Let $a \in \bar S$, then $a \in S$ or $a \in S'$. If $a \in S$ it's trivial that $\forall n\in\mathbb N,\exists x_n \in \mathbb R: |x_n - a| < \frac{1}{n}$, so let's focus in the case where $a \in S'$.

So let $a$ be a limit point of the set $S$. Let $A \in \tau$ be an arbitrary open set such that $a \in A$, then, because $a$ is an limit point: $\exists b \in S: b \in A \wedge b \neq a$.

Because is opened then it is the union of open sets: $a \in A = \bigcup_{i \in I} ]\alpha_i,\beta_i[$ where $I$ is an index set for $i$. Because $a \in A$, there exists an indice set $J \subseteq I$ such that: $a \in ]\alpha_j,\beta_j[, j \in J$.

Let $\varepsilon = \text{min}\{|a - \alpha_j|, |a - \beta_j|\}$, then $]a- \frac{\varepsilon}{n}; a + \frac{\varepsilon}{n}[\ \subseteq\  ]\alpha_j,\beta_j[$, and $]a- \frac{\varepsilon}{n}; a +\frac{\varepsilon}{n}[ \in \tau$.

So, because $a$ is a limit point: $\exists b_n \in S: b_n \in ]a- \frac{\varepsilon}{n}; a +\frac{\varepsilon}{n}[  \ \wedge \ b_n \neq a$

This means that $|b_n - a| < \frac{\varepsilon}{n}$

---

I don't know how to continue from now on. Intuitively I see that it makes sense that $|b_n - a|$ can get close to 0 as we want, but How can I change that $\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: The statement is wrong. $x_n \in \mathbb R$ should be replaced by $x_n \in S$.

Comment: That's right, My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \in S'$ then $(a-\frac 1 n,a+\frac1 n)$ is an open set containing $a$. Hence there exists $x_n \in S$ such that $x _n \in (a-\frac 1 n,a+\frac1 n)\setminus \{a\}$ and this gives $|x_n-a| <\frac  1  n$.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting $ A=\left\lbrace n\in\mathbb{N}\mid\left(\exists x_{n}\in S\right),\ \left|x_{n}-a\right|<\frac{1}{n}\right\rbrace \cdot $

And $ \varphi\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} $ defined as follows : $$ \varphi : 0\mapsto\min{A} ,\ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ k+1\mapsto\min{\left(A\setminus\left\lbrace\varphi\left(0\right),\cdots,\varphi\left(k\right)\right\rbrace\right)} $$

Then $ \left(x_{\varphi\left(n\right)}\right)_{n} $ is a subsequence of $ \left(x_{n}\right)_{n} $, and verifies : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \left|x_{\varphi\left(n\right)}-a\right|<\frac{1}{n} $$

It does converge to $ a $ then. Which means $ a\in\overline{S} \cdot $